# Uploadify 2.1.4 not working in IE8

Tags: uploadify

I have a very annoying problem with uploadify (2.1.4). My application is working in FF, Chrome, IE9 & 10 but not in IE8. I can see my browse button and I'm able to select all the files I'd like but uploadify won't start uploading the files nor are they shown in the queue.

Now here comes the weird part: whenever I clear my browers history, cookies and temporary internet files, uploadify works fine once. So only once. The second time I try, I get the exact same problem as before.

My QueueId != "queue" so this is not the problem.

I've been trying to find a solution for hours now and I'm about to give up so I hope someone here can help me. I can post my code here if it's needed but I don't know if it would do you any good since everything is working fine except in IE8.

Thanks

**Edit:** I'm using jquery-1.9.1